# Regex: Find a word that consists of certain characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of dictionary words, I would like to find any word that consists of (some or all) certain characters of a source word in any order :

For Example:

> Characters (source word) to look for : stainless
>
> Found Words : stainless, stain, net, ten, less, sail, sale, tale, tales, ants, etc.

Also if a letter is found once in the source word it can't be repeated in the found word

> Unacceptable words to find : tent (t is repeated), tall (l is repeated) , etc.
>
> Acceptable words to find : less (s is already repeated in the source word), etc.

Comment: I don't think this is doable with regex.

Answer (score -1):

You  could take this approach:

- Match any sequence of characters that are in the search word, requiring that the match is a word (word-boundaries)
- Prohibit that a certain character occurs more often than it is present in the search word, using a negative look-ahead. Do this for *every* character that is in the search word.

For the given example the regular expression would be:

[`(?!(\S*s){4}|(\S*t){2}|(\S*a){2}|(\S*i){2}|(\S*n){2}|(\S*l){2}|(\S*e){2})\b[stainless]+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/T1wEoP/1)

The biggest part of the pattern deals with the negative look-ahead. For example:

- `(\S*s){4}` would match four times an 's' in a single word.
- `(?!   |   )` places these patterns as different options in a negative look-ahead so that none of them should match.

#### Automation

It is clear that making such a regular expression for a given word needs some work, so that is where you could use some automation. Notepad++ cannot help with that, but in a programming environment it is possible. Here is a little snippet in JavaScript that will give you the regular expression that corresponds to a given search word:

```js
function regClassEscape(s) {
    // Escape "[" and "^" and "-":
    return s.replace(/[\]^-]/g, "\\$&");
}

function buildRegex(searchWord) {
    // get frequency of each letter:
    let freq = {};
    for (let ch of searchWord) {
        ch = regClassEscape(ch);
        freq[ch] = (freq[ch] ?? 0) + 1;
    }
    // Produce negative options (too many occurrences)
    const forbidden = Object.entries(freq).map(([ch, count]) =>
        "(\\S*[" + ch + "]){" + (count + 1) + "}"
    ).join("|");
    // Produce character set
    const allowed = Object.keys(freq).join("");
    return "(?!" + forbidden + ")\\b[" + allowed + "]+\\b";
}


// I/O management

const [input, output] = document.querySelectorAll("input,div");
input.addEventListener("input", refresh);

function refresh() {
    if (/\s/.test(input.value)) {
         output.textContent = "Input should have no white space!";
    } else {
         output.textContent = buildRegex(input.value);
    }
}
refresh();
```

```css
input { width: 100% }
```

```html
Search word:<br>
<input value="stainless">
Regular expression:
<div></div>
```